# How to grant trigger access to a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-grant

I'm getting an error message for a trigger I've successfully created.

I've tried...

```
GRANT SELECT ON OTHER_TABLE TO [me];
call SYS.DBA_ASSIST.GRANT_OBJ_PERMS('dbo.MYTABLE','SELECT','dbo.OTHER_TABLE');`
```

Here is the code for the trigger...

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PREVENT_INVALID_ID
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON dbo.MYTABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE ROW_COUNT NUMBER;
  BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ROW_COUNT 
         FROM [OTHER_TABLE] WHERE OTHER_TABLE_ID = :new.MYTABLE_ID;
  IF ROW_COUNT = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'The ID provided is invalid.');
    END IF;
  END;`
```

The error message in user_errors says, "PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

[image: Screen shot]

Any idea how I can get the trigger to access OTHER_TABLE?

I understand that it is not possible to grant access/authorizations to triggers.  But I'm unclear what code I need to run in order to allow the trigger to work.

Thanks in advance,
josh

Comment: If this is for a Oracle, you cann't name a table  **[OTHER_TABLE]**.  
If OTHER_TABLE_ID  is primary key or a unique index why don't use a foreign key on table dbo.MYTABLE?

Comment: Agree. The standard way - the efficient and **only safe** way - to enforce this rule is with a foreign key constraint. Using a trigger is plain bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `MYTABLE` and `OTHER_TABLE` belong to the same user, no privilege is required:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create table other_table (other_Table_id number);

Table created.

SQL> create table mytable (mytable_id number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger prevent_invalid_id
  2    before insert or update on mytable
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    row_count number;
  6  begin
  7    select count(*) into row_count
  8    from other_table where other_table_id = :new.mytable_id;
  9
 10    if row_count = 0 then
 11       raise_application_error(-20101, 'The ID provided is invalid');
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

However, if they belong to different user, then `OTHER_TABLE`'s owner has to grant `SELECT` privilege to *me*. Though, that's not enough - you have to either precede `OTHER_TABLE` with its owner name (e.g. `other_user.other_table`), or create a synonym in my own schema which points to other user's `OTHER_TABLE`. For example:

```
SQL> drop table other_table;

Table dropped.

SQL> connect mike/lion@xe
Connected.
SQL> create table other_table (other_Table_id number);

Table created.

SQL> grant select on other_table to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect scott/tiger@xe
Connected.
SQL> create or replace trigger prevent_invalid_id
  2    before insert or update on mytable
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    row_count number;
  6  begin
  7    select count(*) into row_count
  8    from MIKE.other_table where other_table_id = :new.mytable_id;
  9
 10    if row_count = 0 then
 11       raise_application_error(-20101, 'The ID provided is invalid');
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Note line 8: `MIKE.other_table`.

Just to show what happens if you omit/remove owner's name:

```
SQL> l8
  8*   from MIKE.other_table where other_table_id = :new.mytable_id;
SQL> c/mike.//
  8*   from other_table where other_table_id = :new.mytable_id;
SQL> l
  1  create or replace trigger prevent_invalid_id
  2    before insert or update on mytable
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    row_count number;
  6  begin
  7    select count(*) into row_count
  8    from other_table where other_table_id = :new.mytable_id;
  9
 10    if row_count = 0 then
 11       raise_application_error(-20101, 'The ID provided is invalid');
 12    end if;
 13* end;
SQL> /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for TRIGGER PREVENT_INVALID_ID:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/8      PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
SQL>
```

See? ORA-00942.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:  GRANT SELECT ON OTHER_TABLE TO dbo

What threw me off is the use the words 'table owner' when I was looking for instructions on how to do this.  I thought I was the table owner.  Rather, it's the schema (dbo) that needs the privileges.